# How to write PDF content in a string to a file in java?

Tags: java

I have a response from a server which contains the PDF. Something like shown below (just shown a short edited version below):

```
%PDF-1.4
%????
9 0 obj
%%EOF
```

Using this string or byte array, how can I create a pdf file ?

I already tried to use the following but it shows blank pages in the pdf

```
OutputStream oos = new FileOutputStream("test.pdf");
oos.write(b);
```

I can see the wholeString in console which is a long string starting with %PDF-1.4 and ending with %%EOF. I also tried to read 8192 byte and write. Still same result :

```
        byte[] buf = wholeString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        OutputStream oos = new FileOutputStream(tpath);

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
        int c = 0;

        while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
            System.out.println();
            oos.write(buf, 0, c);
            oos.flush();
        }

        oos.close();
        is.close();
```

I am using EntityUtils to get the stream:

```
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

The converted string is then sent to another method where I try to write it to a file.

Comment: yes. I have a oos.close() at the end.

Comment: If you have a response from a server, you have bytes. You should not convert those bytes to a string and then convert back to bytes if you can avoid it. That's just asking for bugs.

Comment: The header should look like `%PDF-1.1
%¥±ë`. Those question marks tell me you've corrupted the bytes when converting to a string.

Comment: Actually, I just copied the from my console. I think that is because my console does not show some characters ?

Comment: Actually no, the Windows console doesn't replace bytes it doesn't understand with question marks. That's a Java thing. So they were converted wrong in Java.

Comment: I see the same question marks even if I try to read from a random pdf file and print it on my console using FileInputStream

Comment: What code are you using to print the bytes? I bet they're converted to a String first.

Comment: I just noticed that you mentioned the binary data you received was an edited version, so I deleted my answer. Still, if your actual data is close from what you posted and you can open the PDF without error in Reader, I'm quite confident you've got a regular empty PDF file. Check the [PDF spec](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) to make sure (but you'll need to see the actual binary data for that).

Comment: yes. The data is much bigger than what I have posted. I have just posted the start and end of the data.

Comment: Ok, then I support the string conversion hypothesis. Which technology are you using to retrieve data from the server? Plain HTTP connection? Is it a multipart/form-data response? SOAP? With MTOM? You should be able to retrieve the PDF as binary data, but it depends on both the server (which probably does it right) and your client.

Comment: Just saw your edit. I don't know `EntityUtils`, but could you try to use its [`.toByteArray(Entity)`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toByteArray(org.apache.http.HttpEntity)) method instead of `.toString` ?

Comment: using apache EntityUtils to convert the entity to a string (edited my question to show the same). Also, I am converting it to a string because the entity is sometimes a JSON/xml as well. So, I just convert it to a string and send it to my function where I process it based on content type.

Comment: I think you should be able to check whether to do one or the other depending on the ContentType of the Entity, and decode the answer to String only if relevant. See [`HttpEntity.getContentType()`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContentType())

Comment: There is your problem. The bytes of a PDF are not convertable using UTF-8. Use `toByteArray(Entity)` instead.

Comment: Also, JSON and XML should also be stored and parsed as bytes. NEVER convert them to a String yourself. The JSON- or XML-parser will do any encoding conversion it need by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the discussion in the comments, this should solve your immediate problem:

```
byte[] entityBytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(httpResponse.getEntity());
Files.write(Paths.get("test.pdf"), entityBytes);
```

Anything coming into your program will *always* come in as bytes.

If you're not getting bytes from outside the program, that means some framework or library has already done the decoding, possibly incorrectly.

Be aware as a general rule you should always avoid converting to a String unless:

1. You're 100% sure you need a string.
   (PDF, JSON, or XML should be stored and parsed as bytes, not as a string)
2. You're 100% sure the bytes actually represent a string. This is not the case here, since the bytes represent a PDF, not a string.
3. You're 100% sure which encoding to use to decode the bytes to a string. A PDF is not a UTF-8 string.

Comment: @Aaron It was in response to OP saying that sometimes the data from the server is not a PDF, but XML or JSON instead. I'm trying to be as heavy as possible in my suggestion not to convert bytes to string unless you absolutely have to, since it so often leads to bugs, as demonstrated.

Comment: Right, I forgot the other kind of data he was receiving was specifically XML and JSON, so I agree it makes no sense converting them to String as they are received from the server.

Comment: That's right. The byte to string conversion was creating the problem !